# Viewing results from tags implemented with Google Tag Manager in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have some click events that I want tracked throughout a site and want to set this tracking up with Google Tag Manager.

After setting the tags I am able to use the preview mode for tag manager to verify that they are working firing on the events. However when I go to Analytics I can find where the events are being tracked.

Where can I go to view the data that is being collected?

Answer (score 1):

Analytics events can be found in your standard reports under Behavior > Events.